# Is there a tool to cut a polygon with the outline of a raster layer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, splitting

I would like my polygon layer to be cut into two where the end of the raster layer meets the polygon, is it possible? I've tried to polygonize my raster layer, but that doesn't seem to work. Any recommendations?
I'm working in QGIS 2.18.28.
[image: I would like to split the selected polygon where it meets the black raster area.]

Comment: What goes wrong with polygonize? I would suggest to use raster calculator and create a new raster where all pixels with data have pixel value 1 and nodata pixels have pixel value 0. Then polygonize and use the polygon of value=1 for cutting.